# How to read an array of bytes from a file using datainput stream, and print the array of bytes in java

Tags: java, arrays, datainputstream

I have stored an array of bytes `byte[] testByte; testByte = new byte[]{3,4}` into a file, now I need to read from the file and assign the array of bytes to a variable and print it.

I have done the following code,but i am not able to print the array of bytes

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  InputStream is = null;
  DataInputStream dis = null;

  try{
     // create input stream from file input stream
     is = new FileInputStream("c:\\test.txt");

     // create data input stream
     dis = new DataInputStream(is);

     // count the available bytes form the input stream
     int count = is.available();

     // create buffer
     byte[] bs = new byte[count];

     // read data into buffer
     dis.read(bs);

              }
```

Now how to store the contents in the buffer bs into an array.

Please help to resolve this

Comment: `buffer bs into a array` `bs` is an array

Comment: What do you mean with "i am not able to print the array of bytes"? Which results do you get? Or do you not know how to print the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the content of `bs` buffer using `new String`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      InputStream is = null;
      DataInputStream dis = null;
      int count = 0;
      byte[] bs = null;
      String content = "";

      try{

         is = new FileInputStream("C:\\test.txt");

         dis = new DataInputStream(is);

         count = is.available();

         bs = new byte[count];

         dis.read(bs);

// here is a variable that contains the buffer content as a String
         content = new String(bs);
      } catch (IOException e) {

      } finally {
          is.close();
          dis.close();
      }
      System.out.println(content);
}
```

Edit(Answer to comment):
Well, when we create the `new String()` we instantiate a new String with the `byte[]` value.
But, as you already have an array of bytes, then you can store the value of the String object on it again using:

```
bs = content.getBytes();
```

In advance, don't worry if the print of the bytes are different, like 
*[B@199c55a
[B@faa824*
It's just a name given to the object, but the value is the same on both.

Comment: How can we store the result again back to a byte array

Comment: If we need to print the value what changes has to be made

Comment: It depends on how do you want to print it. What I mean is, the value is on a variable, so you can call it in many ways. Of course, here I made it inside a static block, but it is easy to change.